# Material Design: how to get button text to be regular case (not CAPITAL)?

Tags: android, material-design

Android Material Design button style is making button text to 'CAPITAL' letters.  How can I get back the text with whatever cases (non-capital, capital) that I supply via string.xml?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/product_add_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onAddItemButtonClick"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/row_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/row_padding"
    android:text="@string/add_item"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/blueberry" />
```

string.xml

```
 <string name="add_item">Add Item</string>
```

[image: The button text is capitalized! Not what I want.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Comment: Just tested, works with AppCompact, Holo and Material